# Invert colours of selection/window on Windows 7

Tags: gratis, windows-7, portable

I use Magnifier to invert the entire screen, but I am looking for a solution that does this for only a selection/window.

Requirements:

- free
- select window / select section of screen
- portable

Comment: You can use [Magnifier's lens mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/make-screen-items-bigger-magnifier#1TC=windows-7) which allows you to increase and decrease the size of the magnified region. The only disadvantage is that the region moves along with your mouse cursor.

Comment: @ComFreek Yes, I wanted to select the area and keep it like that, so unfortunately this will not work